# git push stuck and edit one file and add commit but upload all file

Tags: git

I use git push my local file to Gitlab

I use these commend

```
git add .
git commit -m "test"
git push XXX XXX
```

I just edit one file in the folder but it seem to upload all file and stuck like below and .

```
Enumerating objects: 382, done.
Counting objects: 100% (382/382), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (344/344), done.
Writing objects: 100% (358/358), 27.78 MiB | 5.06 MiB/s, done.
Total 358 (delta 244), reused 6 (delta 2), pack-reused 0
```

I found some solution to fix it and set

```
git config –global sendpack.sideband false
git config –local sendpack.sideband false
```

and set

```
git config http.postBuffer 824288000
```

but still not work

Please help me.

Comment: There may be some misunderstanding here regarding how Git works.  A Git commit conceptually captures _every_ file in your project, so the output you are seeing does not necessarily strike me as being wrong.

Comment: By stuck, you mean you let it sit for 20 minutes and the command still hadn't finished?

Comment: For the record: `git add .` adds all files from the current directory and subdirectories, regardless of being tracked or untracked. It is very well possible that gigabytes of files were added to that single commit. If only changes to tracked files should be added to the next commit, use `git add -u`

Comment: sorry. but until now it still not finish. and gitlab not update

Comment: And I try 'git add -u' git push XXX . and not work..